# Woocommerce custom redirect after product added to cart via AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to redirect to a custom url after woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart. I have seen plenty of solutions but none using AJAX. The redirect is refreshing the page instead of redirecting to the custom url, if someone could give me a hand, I would really appreciate it!!

```
add_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', 'm_custom_redirect');
    function m_custom_redirect( $product_id ) {
        // add your check if certain product should trigger the redirect
        if ( $product_id == 9904 ) {
            // custom redirect url
            $custom_redirect_url = get_permalink(3751);
            $data = array(
                'error'       => true,
                'product_url' => $custom_redirect_url
            );
            wp_send_json( $data );
            exit;
        }
    }
```

source: https://mircian.com/2016/10/13/woocommerce-ajax-add-cart-custom-redirect/